# PHP: Include inside include with different root

Tags: php, include, directory

So I have:

Page A - `/WWW/index.php`

Page B - `/WWW/folder/index.php`

Page C - `/WWW/assets/functions.php`

I want to be able to use the same line of code to include Page C on Page A and Page B.

Right now for Page A: `include "/assets/functions.php";`

Page B: `include "../assets/functions.php";`

The "../" is what bugs me. Depending on how many times the file is nested in folder I have to add a "../"

I tried: `include dirname(__FILE__) . "/assets/functions.php";`

But it works on Page A and not Page B.

Also in the function.php I want to be able to include other PHP files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]. "/assets/functions.php");
```

`require_once` is used to include your file once.

`$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` is used to get your root directory.

Comment: Errors are not displayed by default. I'm checking by have a variable on function.php and on both index.php and /folder/index.php I'm echoing it and neither is echoing.

Comment: Sorry, I should have had error reporting on in the first place. I would have figured it out without needing to ask this. I'm building a new site on my site under /new/ and I forgot to add that part before assets. I assumed it already new that as the root too.

Answer (score -1):

try it

```
require rtrim(dirname(__FILE__), '/\\') . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'my_file.php';
```